# How can I detemine the parameters needed by the_widget()?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, template-tags

I'm working with an old (now unmaintained) widget, which only allows one instance.

Since I want to have a different sidebar on the homepage and I want this widget on both sidebars, I figure I need to do one of two things:

1. Update the plugin to use the new widget API
2. Use `the_widget()` to manually drop the widget into the custom sidebar

I've opted to do the latter as a quick fix, but can't figure out the parameters needed to get it to display.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to change any of the settings for the widget, you may be able to use the [Duplicate Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-widget/) widget.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget).

*Furthermore: If you really want help in detail, you'll have to provide much more information (pastebin or similar link to code) in your Q.*

Comment: OK, to be clear, I've read the documentation and I can see what parameters are expected, but I don't know where to find the values to pass to them. My question is more: "where do I find the values" than "what values do I need".

Comment: You're talking about an old - now unmaintained - widget. Please share a link to the widget code. _About "what values do I need": This depends on your plugin and as long as I haven't seen it, I don't know what arguements could be expected. If you're talking about the default, built in widgets, then you'll find any information on the link (search for "default")._